# Uncaught TypeError: equipo.data is undefined using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the following problem trying to traverse an array of objects and I don't know where the problem is.

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  const [equipo, setEquipo] = React.useState([]);

  // Constructor
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Magic - React";
    obtenerDatos();
  }, []);

  // Metodo que recoge info de una Api
  const obtenerDatos = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=set&q=e%3Augin&unique=prints");
    const info = await data.json();
    setEquipo(info);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {equipo.data.map((item) => (
          <li>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the JSON Api where I search the info.

https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=set&q=e%3Augin&unique=prints

I try to show the images and the text of the cards in the HTML. I am new with React. Please help and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {equipo?.data?.map((item) => (
          <li>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you too much for your help. The project is running now.

Comment: No problem.  Basically the component was trying to render the data before the async function returned. The ? checks to see whether the data exists before rendering.

Comment: It reminds me of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

This is your issue:

```js
const [equipo, setEquipo] = React.useState([]);
```

On the first render, before the API call has returned, you're attempting to access the `.data` field of an empty array. Instead, you need to initialize equipo with:

```js
const [equipo, setEquipo] = React.useState({data: []});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying so quickly. I'll keep this in mind for future issues with React.